# Convert from hex to float in MatLab

Tags: matlab, binary, numbers

I'm working with a device that send to me hex values, and I need convert those values to his real float value.
Here you can see the conversion table:

```
01 1111 1111 1111  --> 1.99975g
01 1111 1111 1110  --> 1.99950g
...
...
00 0000 0000 0001  --> 0.00025g
00 0000 0000 0000  --> 0.00000g
11 1111 1111 1111  --> -0.00025g
...
...
10 0000 0000 0001  --> -1.99975g
10 0000 0000 0000  --> -2.00000g
```

I did a LookUpTable to solve my problem, but I'm just wondering if there are a better way to do it in MatLab.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your title says "hex to int", your question body says "hex to float"...

Comment: its not even "hex" more like binary..

Comment: You may have a look at [two's complement](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5485-twos-complement-for-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @zellus is right. This is a variation on 2's compliment. It uses a 'byte' size of 14 bits and then after converting to an integer (call it an index), multiplies by a scaling factor of 2/8192. This maps an index value of 8192 to 2g. Like @Amro, this method has the small rounding errors but I hope it shows you what is going on a little better (it *might* be computationally faster as well, I can't test it because I don't have a MATLAB license)

The steps are

1. If the incoming number has a sentinel 1, the number is negative. Else, it is positive. Drop the sentinel number regardless.
2. Convert the binary number to an integer
3. If the integer is negative, subtract 1
4. Multiply the integer by a scaling factor of 2/8192.

Applying this to your data yields

```
INCOMING      PROCESS SENTINEL       RAW     INDEX       SCALED
01 1111 1111 1111 --> +1 1111 1111 1111 --> +8191 -->  8191 -->  1.99976g
01 1111 1111 1110 --> +1 1111 1111 1110 --> +8190 -->  8190 -->  1.99951g
...
00 0000 0000 0001 --> +0 0000 0000 0001 -->    +1 -->     1 -->  0.00024g
00 0000 0000 0000 --> +0 0000 0000 0000 -->    +0 -->     0 -->  0.00000g
11 1111 1111 1111 --> -0 0000 0000 0000 -->    -0 -->    -1 --> -0.00024g
...
10 0000 0000 0001 --> -1 1111 1111 1110 --> -8190 --> -8191 --> -1.99976g
10 0000 0000 0000 --> -1 1111 1111 1111 --> -8191 --> -8192 --> -2.00000g
```

Just from looking at it, it seems like a natural scaling factor would have been 0.00025. Is it possible that 01 1111 1111 1111 is supposed to  2.04775g?

I am assuming you are trying to interface with an accelermoter (or other device) that is on a 2G to -2G scale. If documentation said 2G to -2G, they might have been rounding a true full range of 2.04775G to -2.05G.

If you aren't familiar with it, look up two-compliment. It is cool stuff. Binary numbers practically add themselves in it.

Edit: I made a huge omission on my first step. If the first bit is a one, you also need to NOT each bit.

Comment: You are right, I'm receiving data from an accelerometer, which send me the information in wireless way. I didn't write the code of the accelerometer, but I now that it send me the raw data, so I have to convert the data and show it in a PC.

Comment: I did a LookUpTable that goes from -2g to 1.99975 (I take this values from the datasheet of the accelerometer)

Answer (score 1):

If your binary representation is stored as a string in the variable `b`, this will print what you're looking for:

```
integer_part = bin2dec(b(2));
fraction_part = bin2dec(b(4:end)) * 2^-12;

value = integer_part + fraction_part;

if b(1) == '1'
    value = -2 + value;
end

disp(value)
```

Comment: It does not give the same result, but I think you're getting close... The data given looks like some sort of signed [binary fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary). We really need more info from the OP

Comment: I verified this before posting; I agree, they are different, but only in the least significant digit (and only by 1). My best guess was that this is actually due to rounding error on the OP's behalf. If I'm wrong, this solution isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest I could get without more info about the binary representation used:

```
%# values stored as strings
b = [ ...
  '01111111111111'
  '01111111111110'
  '00000000000001'
  '00000000000000'
  '11111111111111'
  '10000000000001'
  '10000000000000'
];

%# convert to numbers
val = sum(bsxfun(@times, b-'0', [-2 0.5.^(0:size(b,2)-2)]), 2);
```

The result:

```
>> fprintf('%.5f\n', val)
1.99976
1.99951
0.00024
0.00000
-0.00024
-1.99976
-2.00000
```